# Autoresizing widgets in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, autoresize

How to make widget change size after it's parent window changed size? I have a widget which should match 30% of parent width and 100% of height.

There is no tutorial information in google. I've just found that it can be done via layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Height should happen automatically if the widget is expanding. For the 30% width you need to set the stretch factors in the widgets to have a 3:7 ratio where 7 is the sum of all the other widgets next to this one.

For anything more you have to show some code of what you have tried.

Comment: But what about creating two bloks in scrollbox of 100% height and 100% width of parent?

Comment: That sounds like a different question